# latex R chunk output not decorated

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

When using bookdown, if I have an R chunk where I want to show output but not the R code, the default decorations are missing in the pdf output.

For example, this example has a nicely formatted chunk (gray background, coloured text, etc.)

````
```{r test1, echo=TRUE}
1:4
```
````

But this one does not have any decoration.

````
```{r test2, echo=FALSE}
1:4
```
````

The contrast is easily seen below.

[image]

How can I produce the second example with the gray background and coloured text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give the output block a language name, e.g.,

````
```{r test2, echo=FALSE, class.output='r'}
1:4
```
````

By default, text output is generated to

````
```
```
````

With `class.output='lang'`, text output is generated to

````
```lang
```
````

Without the language name, code blocks will not be syntax highlighted.